# Bitwise operators in JavaScript as flags on a state

Tags: javascript, arrays, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I am trying to install some logic into a piece of JS I am working on that will simply add/remove flags depending on some conditions.

It primarily consists of two steps

1. Build object based on some stateful data
2. Hand off to post initialization method to parse data array of objects

In `Step 1`, there is a 'status' property, which can have a number of flags:

```
  - INCOMPLETE      = 1
  - COMPLETE        = 2
  - CURRENT         = 4
  - NOT_APPLICABLE  = 8
```

When the object array is parsed, it checks each item to see what status flags are set:

```
  if CURRENT is set, give class 'item-current' to node
  if INCOMPLETE is set, give class 'item-incomplete' to node
  if COMPLETE is set, give class 'item-complete' to node
  if NOT_APPLICABLE is set, give class 'item-not-applicable' to node
```

As the user interacts with the page, the flags will change on the object array - when a user 'completes' a segment, the status for that object property will remove the `INCOMPLETE` flag, and add the `COMPLETE` flag.

I tried doing this this way:

```
   let v = [
       {
         name: "Item 1",
         status: COMPLETE
       },
       {
         name: "Item 2",
         status: INCOMPLETE | CURRENT
       },
       {
         name: "Item 3",
         status: INCOMPLETE
       }
   ];

   // Moving on to step 3

   v[1].status = v[1].status ^ INCOMPLETE ^ CURRENT | COMPLETE; // remove incomplete and current from Item 2, marking as COMPLETE
   v[2].status = v[2].status | CURRENT;  // marks Item 3 as current step, but not yet complete
```

In the above scenario, `Item 1` has been completed, and the user has moved on to `Item 2` which is still INCOMPLETE, and CURRENT step. For some reason, when I am evaluating the conditions of the flags, it gives me (what seems like) unexpected behavior.

I have tried removing the flag by doing these:
 `v[1].status   ^= CURRENT`
 `v[1].status   = v[1].status ^ CURRENT`

And comparing by:

```
if ((v[1].status & COMPLETE) === COMPLETE) {
  // is complete
} else {
  // not complete
}
```

But yet I still seem to face flags seeming like they are still set, or unexpectedly getting set. Is there an easier way to do this?

The desired result, would be a case where I can set the flag, remove the flag, and check to see if the flag is set - using constants that are bitmasks.

Why is INCOMPLETE | CURRENT the same thing as INCOMPLETE ^ CURRENT?

I am struggling with removing a bit from the mask and returning that value it seems.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Bitwise operators operate on integers. If you want to have separate independent flags, you need to number them as powers of 2: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, They are 1,2,4,8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use bitwise operations like this with values that are not powers of 2.

The value 3 could be any of the follwing values:

- `CURRENT`
- `COMPLETE | INCOMPLETE`
- `CURRENT | COMPLETE`
- `CURRENT | INCOMPLETE`
- `CURRENT | COMPLETE | INCOMPLETE`

There's no way to tell which combination it is.

Change the values to

- COMPLETE = 1
- COMPLETE = 2
- CURRENT = 4
- NOT_APPLICABLE = 8

and it's so easy to do bitwise operations with powers of 2.

Comment: Why is COMPLETE | CURRENT the same thing as COMPLETE ^ CURRENT

Comment: My values are actually powers of 2, not 1,2,3,4 - it was a typo on my part. Sorry!

Comment: Can you unconditionally remove a bitmask flag? Like say, you have A = 1, and then do A ^ 4 - it returns 5; ideally I'd like it to return 1.

Comment: `5 & (0xff ^ 4)` - `0xff ^ 4` will set bit pattern to b11111011 which you then & with 5 (b00000101) to get 1 (b00000001). Just make sure that the value you use for `0xff` is greater than the largest flag